# Scrapy post error 405 in react generated page

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to learn about scrapy to avoid the overhead of spidering with selenium for a site that requires authentication. 
- The website is written in React.js.
- It contains the http tag 
- Email  tag is 'name=email'
- password  tag is 'name=password'
- I changed the scrapy User-Agent to Chrome for windows
- It seems to be the wrong form data from what I gathered in other post, but why?

I am getting response 405 from post. The same tags work in Java Selenium but that is a headless browser. Any help in understanding why would be helpful.

Page (inspect element in Chrome):

```
<form value="login"><label for="email">Email* </label><input class="userInput" type="text" name="email" autocomplete="email" required=""><label for="password">Password* </label><input class="userInput" type="password" name="password" required=""><input type="submit" value="Login"><div style="margin-top: 1em;"><input class="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"><p style="margin-left: 35px;">Remember Me</p><a href="/student/register"><p>Register</p></a></div><button>Reset Password</button><span style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 20px;"></span></form>
```

spider.py

```
class TestSpider(Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ["mysite.io"]
    start_urls = ["https://mysite.io/"]

    def start_requests(self):
        # req = Request("https://mysite.io/student/login",
        #               callback=self.logged_in)
        data = {'email': 'email@domain.com', 'password': 'password'}
        req = FormRequest("https://mysite.io/login",
                          formdata=data,
                          callback=self.logged_in)
        print("run1-----------------------------------")
        yield req

    def logged_in(self, response):
        print("run2-----------------------------------")
        print(response.url)
        yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parse)
```

I expect it to log in and go the next page so I can other stuff, but I get error 405 on .../login. There is a parse method in the real code, but I didn't think it was needed here.

I just tried splash-scrapy.
spider.py:

```
class TestSpider(Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ["website.io"]
    start_urls = ["https://website.io/"]

    def start_requests(self):
        req = SplashRequest("https://website.io/login",
                            self.log_in, args={'wait': 0.5})

        print("start-----------------------------------")
        yield req

    def log_in(self, response):
        print(response.body)
        data = {'email': 'email@domain.com',
                'password': 'pass'}
        req = SplashFormRequest(response.url,
                                formdata=data,
                                callback=self.logged_in)
        print("log in --------------------------------")
        yield req

    def logged_in(self, response):
        print("logged in-----------------------------------")
        yield SplashRequest(response.url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print("nexturl---------------------------------")
        print(response.css('li.next a').attrib['href'])
```

Responce.body does not have page content. I tried to render the page on the splash API at 8050 and the page was blank. How can I make this work?

Comment: This issue seems to be due to the dynamic pages in React. If you have an example of how to use scrapy splash for login, that would be great. I don't want to use the selenium driver because I need a lightweight implementation.

Comment: The script with scrapy-splash would work, but there is something special about the page. Robot.txt was ignored and it still doesn't work. However, most other sites do render. The main site can be rendered, too, but a some pages that happen to require auth could not be rendered.

Comment: See See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I was able to resolve the issue by passing additional data in the next request in the header. If anyone else is looking at this, look at networking in inspect elements and pass all information in the request headers to emulate a regular browser. This includes cookies, JWT, referrer, etc.